# Why slicing element from list do not return list?

Tags: list, perl

When working with lists in scalar context the last element is returned:

```
@l =  qw/ a b c d /;
print scalar ( 1, @l ); # prints 4
```

The last element of the list is `@l`, its length in scalar context is 4

So the last element is `@l`.

**Why when I do slice I do not get this element?**

```
print (( 1, @l )[1]); # prints 'a'. expect: abcd
```

PS. Maybe I should ask: Why flattening is not happened in first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the difference in behaviour between list and scalar context, and the fact that `scalar` is an *operator* and not a subroutine call. `scalar` can take only a single operand, so if you pass more than one parameter then they are put into scalar context. This is unlike ordinary subroutine calls where  the parameters are always in list context.

In *scalar context* the comma operator evaluates and discards its left-hand operand and then evaluates its right-hand operand. So `scalar(1, @l)` evaluates and discards `1` and then evaluates `@l`. As you say, that is 4 because `@l` has four elements

A list slice, unsurprisingly, imposes *list context*, and in list context commas separate the elements of a list and arrays and hashes are flattened. So `(1, @l)[1]` is the same as `(1, qw/ a b c d /)[1]` which is `a`

Perl array operators like `push` and `pop` behave in a similar way. `push @l, 1` wouldn't be much use if it behaved the same way as an ordinary subroutine and expanded to `push 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1`

Answer (score 4):

In your first example you force scalar context by using `scalar` .
In scalar content `,` is interpreted as **scalar** binary operator returning right side argument.

```
@l =  qw/ a b c d /;
@m = (1, @l); # (1,@l) is interpreted in list context
print scalar(@l); # prints 4
print scalar(@m); # prints 5
print scalar('a',@l); # ('a',@l) is interpreted in scalar context
                      # prints scalar(@l) 
print scalar(@l,'a'); # (@l,'a') is interpreted in scalar context
                      # prints a
```

`perldoc -f scalar`

> **scalar EXPR**
>   Forces EXPR to be interpreted in scalar context and returns the value of EXPR.

`man perlop`

> **Comma Operator**
>    Binary "," is the comma operator.  **In scalar context it evaluates its
>    left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right
>    argument and returns that value.**  This is just like C's comma operator.
>    In list context, it's just the list argument separator, and inserts
>    both its arguments into the list.  These arguments are also evaluated
>    from left to right.